# How can i split json['total] so i can get total price only

Tags: javascript, json, cart, opencart2.x

I have made my own styles for `cart.tpl`.
but when I add item or remove it gets `json'[total]` which returns

`xx item(s)- $xxx.xx`

Is there a way to split that so I can get quantity and total price separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function.

```
"10 item(s)- $254.98".split('-')[0].split(' ')[0]; //Gives "10"

"10 item(s)- $254.98".split('-')[1].trim();//Gives "$254.98"
```

If you want to do Arithmetic operations with these numbers you will have to use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` to convert these to numbers.